# Proving a subspace of $l^1_\infty$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, compactness

Any help on this would be appreciated.

I'm trying to prove that the subspace $(E,\rho)$ is compact.

$$E = \{\{x_n\}_n \in X: |x_n|\leq1/(3^n)\text{ for every }n\}$$

$$X=\{\{x_n\}_n \in X: \sum \limits^\infty |x_n| < \infty\}$$

$\rho(x,y$) = $\sum \limits^\infty$ |$x_n - y_n$|

So as I understand it, the metric space is the space of sequences of numbers that converge in absolute value. We're restricting that space to a subset E, and E is given as sequences where the first item in the sequence is less than 1/3, the second is less than 1/9, etc.

So I know that if $(X,\rho)$ is compact and $E$ is a subset of $X$, $(E, \rho)$ is compact iff $E$ is closed in $X$. So I need to prove that $E$ is closed.

I'm just having trouble showing that the set is closed. I wanted to prove by contradiction, and say that if $E$ isn't closed, there must be some sequence in $E$ where the sequence converges outside of $E$. I'm confused because the limit of a sequence is a number (don't all these sequences converge to $0$??), but how can the number $0$ be in $E$ if $E$ is a set of sequences? Yeah, I'm confused.

Comment: Every element (which is a sequence) as a sequence converges to $0$, but here you have sequence of sequences

Comment: So I need to prove that a sequence of these sequences will converge? I know how to prove that an l^p space converges, by finding the candidate pointwise limit sequence and then showing that this is in fact the limit of the sequence of sequences. So is that what I do here as well?

Comment: No, you need to prove (to see that is closed) that if you have a convergent sequence of sequences inside $E$ its limit is inside $E$

Comment: Okay I see what you're saying. I would know how to do that if I have a candidate limiting sequence, but I'm not sure I know how to do that in general. Do you have any tips or a place where I could look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space $\mathcal{l}^{1}(\mathbb{N})$ consisting of absolutely summable sequences $x=\{ x_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space under the norm
$$
                           \|x\|_{1} = \sum_{n}|x_{n}|.
$$
And your metric $\rho$ is generated by this norm: $\rho(x,y)=\|x-y\|_1$. The closed unit ball of $X$ is *not* compact because $X$ is inifinite dimensional. So you cannot just show that $E$ is closed subset of $X$ or of its closed unit ball in order to prove compactness. That's not enough.

To show that $E= \{ x \in X : |x_n| \le 1/3^{n} \}$ is compact, suppose $\{ x_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset E$. Each $x_k$ is itself a sequence with $n$ element $(x_k)_n$. That is,
$$
             x_k = \{ (x_k)_1, (x_k)_2, (x_k)_3,\cdots \}.
$$
For a fixed $j$, the sequence $\{ (x_{k})_j \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a bounded sequence with uniform bound $1/3^{j}$. So you can choose a subsequence $\{ x_{k_{l}}\}_{l=1}^{\infty}\subset E$ such that $\{(x_{k_{l}})_1\}_{l=1}^{\infty}$ converges. Then you can choose a subsequence $\{ x_{k_{l_{m}}}\}_{m=1}^{\infty}\subset E$ so that $\{ (x_{k_{l_{m}}})_1\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{ (x_{k_{l_{m}}})_2\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ both converge. By using the Cantor diagonalization process, you can find a subsequence $\{ x_{k_{n}}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset E$ of the original sequence $\{ x_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset E$ such that the following limits exists
$$
                  y_j = \lim_{k} \;(x_{k_{n}})_j ,\;\;\; j=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
Because $x_{k_{n}} \in E$, then $|(x_{k_{n}})_{j}| \le 1/3^{j}$ and, therefore, $|y_j| \le 1/3^{j}$ follows from the above limit, which puts $y \in E$. To show that $\{ x_{k_{n}} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges in $X$ to $y \in E$, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Choose $J$ large enough that
$$
                        \sum_{j=J+1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^{j}} < \epsilon/2.
$$
Then choose $N$ large enough that
$$
                 \sum_{j=1}^{J}|(x_{k_{n}})_j-y_j| < \epsilon/2,\;\;\; n \ge N.
$$
Then $\rho(x_{k_{n}},y) < \epsilon$ for $n \ge N$. Because $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, then $\lim_{n} x_{k_{n}}=y$ in the metric space. Hence $E$ is sequentially compact and, therefore, compact.

Comment: Can I see if I'm understanding correctly? So you have each sequence x_k, and basically for each index i, the sequence (x_k)_i is bounded by 1/3^i and therefore has a convergent subsequence, which is x_k_l. I'm not sure what the subsequence of that subsequence gets, though. I'm still a little confused about that part and why you're saying that both 1 and 2 converge.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the same proof that shows l^p spaces are complete to show that this subspace is complete? Because a complete metric space is closed.

Comment: @MSUhelp : First comment. You need a subsequence of $\{ x_{k_{n}}\}$ for which *all* coordinates $(x_{n_{k}})_i$ converge. That's why you choose the first subsequence to get the convergence of the first coordinate $(x_{n_k})_1$. Then a subsequence of that first subsequence for which the second coordinate $(x_{n_{k_l}})_2$ converges automatically has a convergent first coordinate, too. Keep going and choose the Cantor diagonal subsequence for which *all* coordinates converge.

Comment: @MSUhelp : Second comment. Completeness follow from compactness. However, compactness does not follow from completeness. A set is compact in a metric space iff it is complete *and* totally bounded.

Comment: @ T.A.E.: Thank you so much for explaining! I understand much better now. My only remaining question is, how do you know that there even exists a subsequence for which all coordinates converge? Isn't that essentially what we're proving? I see how you can get a convergent sequence for which the first coordinate converges and a separate one for which the second coordinate converges, etc. But how do you know that you can get a subsequence of the first subsequence for which the second coordinate also converges? It might rely on the Cantor diagonal subsequence argument that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @MSUhelp : Please reread what I wrote in the comment. Choose a subsequence so the first coordinate converges, and then a subsequence of the subsequence so that the second coordinate converges; automatically the subsequence of the subsequence converges in the first and second coordinates. Eventually, using the Cantor diagonal, you get a subsequence of every one of the sub-sub-sub-....-sequences that converges in every coordinate.

Comment: I see that. I'm just wondering if it's possible to choose a subsequence of the original sequence so the first coordinate converges, but it's not possible to choose a subsequence of that subsequence so that the second coordinate converges. Like maybe the subsequence that has convergence in first coordinates doesn't have any subsequences with convergence in the second coordinates. Is it just always possible to choose such subsequences?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I guess that is possible. Sorry for my confusion. Thanks so much for taking the time to explain everything! I don't have enough points or whatever to give you an upvote.

Comment: @MSUhelp : That's okay. Just glad to help.

Comment: @COVID-20 Hello, I am reading this post and I'd like to know whether I can prove a more general version of this statement. Can I substitute $\frac{1}{3^n}$, the dominating infinite series, with any $\{a_n\}$ s.t. $\sum_{n}|a_n|$ is convergent? Should $\{a_n\}\in\ell^1$? To prove this, can I still apply a similar diagonalization argument as yours? Thank you.